# Best way to represent delivery route, city, and driver

Tags: python, database, odoo

Say I have a delivery route (eg. Monday, Tuesday,etc..). Each route has a list of cities/suburbs that are visited on that route (A-Town, B-Town, C-Town), and a list of drivers that do each city (eg Driver X takes A-Town and B-town, DriverY takes C-Town).

What is the most adaptable way to represent this in terms of designing the classes, such that it would be possible to have overlap between drivers? So that a driver make share parts of a route but on different days. Each town may have multiple delivery days, with different drivers on each of those days. EG A-Town may have Driver X on Monday, but Driver Y on Tuesday. I have a delivery address, and I'd search for the next possible weekday that I could deliver.

Right now I have a text file where each driver has a list of cities done per each weekday like so:

[MONDAY]
DRIVER X: A-Town, B-Town, G-Town
DRIVER Y: A-Town, C-Town, Q-Town

I feel like there  is a smarter way of achieving kind of structure.

I'm using Python 2.7 (openERP/Odoo). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the distance between the towns/mapping/most efficient route is irrelevant, as we promise certain cities are done on certain days rather than optimize a delivery schedule.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you two different ways.

First :

Create different classes to represents your structure :
- class driver
- class map (to represent the set of towns)
- class town

The map can be represented by a graph (with number of driver 'roots') with distance (in time) as weighting (for example 1(day) between A and B if there is a driver that can make the travel (Monday-Tuesday)). You start at a possible node (A-Town for driver X for example) and search a path from your start point to your target.

I let you find how to represent the others informations and how to make the graph.

Second (And better I think if I well understood your problem):

Make a linear program to represent this one.
With CPLEX, you will have the optimal solution to make the transport.
In fact, this way isn't incompatible with the last. You could represent the situation by a graph and create constraints with this one and call cplex with (even in python via API or by system call)

Comment: Hiya. Thanks for the comment. The actual map / route optimization is not something we actually do; this is purely for storing the information, not calculating the most efficient route. EG We promise delivery for Town A on a Monday, always.  Due to several reasons I wont get into here, we dont reschedule our routes to be more efficient but rather maintain standard delivery days.